# Trying to output directory listing to a csv file

Tags: python, directory

I'm quite new to Python and programming in general, so hope you won't mind me asking a perhaps very basic question.

I'm using the following code to output a directory listing to excel.

```
import os

a = open('H:\output.csv', "w")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'.'):
    for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

The problem is that some of the filenames are being cut off and instead of being entirely contained in column A, the last 6 or so characters are getting split into column B.

Additionally, there is a linebreak between each row, which ideally I would like to get rid of.

Lastly, I'd like to have a second column which contains only the filename, rather than the full path.

Comment: Do the columns that get messed-up have anything in common, like do they all have a certain character in them (like a backslash) or something?

Comment: Yes, you're right....it looks like the rows which have part of the file path in column B all have a comma in the name. After the comma, the rest of the file name is shifted into column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It encloses the file paths and file names each in double quote characters (`"`) which I think might avoid the problem. I also had to specify an encoding for the output file because on my system paths are Unicode but the default mode for files is not.

```
import os

a = open('dirfiles.csv', "w", encoding='utf8')
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'.'):
    for filename in files:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        a.write('"%s","%s"' % (f, filename) + os.linesep)
```

Comment: That's great, that fixed the file names being chopped in two and pushed into column B....thank you so much.

Comment: Can I be cheeky and ask if you would know how to also list file names in column B? :)